# iPhone - designing my own viewController transition

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, viewcontroller

My app have a bunch of viewControllers and I am trying to design my own animation transition from one viewController to the other.

I have found this

```
- (void)transitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

but this does not appear to allow designing my own transition curve.

What I want is to create effects like elastic bouncing when the new viewControllers hits the final position and stuff like that. I like to add my own keyframes to the animation curve.

How do I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to design your own transition you could create a category to UIViewController and write the animations yourself. There are only basic animations already available.

This is how you could do the interface:

*.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController(Transitions)

- (void) presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withPushDirection: (NSString *) direction;
- (void) dismissViewControllerWithPushDirection:(NSString *) direction;

@end
```

*.m file

```
#import "UIViewControllerWithTransitions.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIViewController(Transitions)

- (void) presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withPushDirection: (NSString *) direction {

    [CATransaction begin];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = direction;
    transition.duration = 0.25f;
    transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    transition.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];        
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^ {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(transition.duration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];        
        });
    }];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:NULL];

    [CATransaction commit];

}

- (void) dismissViewControllerWithPushDirection:(NSString *) direction {

    [CATransaction begin];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = direction;
    transition.duration = 0.25f;
    transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    transition.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];        
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^ {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(transition.duration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];        
        });
    }];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];

    [CATransaction commit];

}

@end
```

and this is a sample call:

```
[self presentViewController: myVC withPushDirection:@"fromRight"];
```

Comment: thanks. I have verified that it works with keyframed animation. Thanks.

Comment: I have none substantially good yet, I have just created some simple key framed animation to test if this answer would work.

Comment: it can be done alot easier than that but the answer is valid.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an easier solution?