# How to set custom dismissal animation for UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I know this is how you set an animation for modal storyboard segue or `presentViewController:animated:completion`:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return [[BounceAnimationController alloc] init];
}
```

But how do you set one for dismissing a view controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIViewController – issue with custom dismiss transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085867/uiviewcontroller-issue-with-custom-dismiss-transition)

Answer (score 0):

I went for a look at the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate codes and found out this method does it:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return [[MyAnimationController alloc] init];
}
```